# Asymptotics of $ f_c(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor cn\rfloor}{n\choose k} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Define
$$
f_c(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor cn\rfloor}{n\choose k}
$$
for some fixed constant $c$ (say, $0<c<1/2$). What are the asymptotics of $f_c(n)$ as $n\to\infty$?

It seems that this should be simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I searched the standard references (MathWorld, Wikipedia, DLMF, etc.) but didn't see any identities for this type of sum.

---

Edit: It seems, numerically, that with
$$
g(c)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(f_c(n))/n
$$
that $g(c)$ exists and is positive for $c>0$. (Of course $g(1)=\log2.$) Is this so, and can $g(c)$ be computed efficiently? Or even more courageously, what is the error in approximating $f_c(n)$ as $\exp(n\cdot g(c))$?

Comment: FYI, I edited your title. Very hard to find duplicates when there are like ~1000 questions titled a variant of "sum with binomial coefficients" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean  $\lfloor c n\rfloor$ rather than $\lfloor c k \rfloor$ in that sum.

$$f_c(n)/2^n = \mathbb P(S_n \le \lfloor c n \rfloor)$$

where $S_n$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $1/2$.
By [Large Deviations theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory),

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac1n \log f_c(n) = - c \log c - (1-c) \log(1-c) $$

Comment: Yes, this matches my calculations exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no identity, as $n$ is growing to infinite, $cn$ is to. So the limit is the infinte sum of the coeficient which are a growing infinite sequence, the limit is infinite.

Comment: Yes, it's infinite, that's why I want to know about its asymptotic growth. For example, $f_1(n)=2^n$, but how much smaller is $f_{1/3}(n)$ asymptotically?